# How do I install Idle on ubuntu the ide that comes with python?

Tags: python3

I'm new to ubuntu and I don't know how to install .tar.gz files + I already have python installed from pycharm I guess. 
I read that you can't install python twice it will mess up everything ...

Also why I'm I restricted to posting question every 40 minutes?

Comment: Related to 40 minutes limit on [meta.se]: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/468333)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```